# Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, charts, laravel-5.3

I do a project with laravel 5.3 aaand
I want to make a chart with https://erik.cat/projects/Charts/docs/4#installation and i want it to be dynamic with the labels field being an array of the titles of the projects that the user is involved into with its tasks (hope i am clear)

untill now i have something like this

```
$idUser = Auth::user()->id;

        $tasksUsed = DB::table('user_task')
            ->join('tasks', 'tasks.id', '=', 'user_task.task_id')
            ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
            ->select('projects.title')->where('user_task.user_id',$idUser)->get();

           // dd($tasksUsed->toArray());

        $chart = Charts::create('donut', 'morris')
            // ->view('custom.line.chart.view') // Use this if you want to use your own template
            ->title('My nice chart')
            ->labels($tasksUsed->toArray())
            ->values([3,4])
            ->dimensions(300,300)
            ->responsive(false);
```

and it gives me this error and i don't know how to solve it

```
   Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string 
...\vendor\consoletvs\charts\resources\views\morris\donut.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your `donut.blade.php` you are doing something like this:

```
{!! $chart !!}
```

Because `$chart` is an object it cannot be printed as string

Comment: in my view i do this: {!! $chart->render() !!}

Comment: Very close. Check the documentation of that library, because `$chart->render()` is returning a object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $chart = Charts::create('donut', 'morris')
            // ->view('custom.line.chart.view') // Use this if you want to use your own template
            ->title('My nice chart')
            ->labels($tasksUsed->pluck('title')->toArray())
            ->values([3,4])
            ->dimensions(300,300)
            ->responsive(false);
```

This is the solution